# Priority Queue Using Dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, queue, priority-queue

I can't figure out why my popQue is not working. 
I am trying to create a Priority Queue using Dict in Python. I am new to this so I am aware this could be a naive approach of creating a priority Queue. If you know of one that already exists(uses dict) and can be understood easily, I would like to take reference from it too. Thank you!

```
class priorQueue():

     def __init__(self):
         self.que = {}   # a dict that maps vertex key to its priority number (here, its weight)
         self.small_key = +999  #used as a counter to find vertex with min weights
         self.small_v = None 

    def popQue(self): # vertex with min weight so far is returned. not same as delete
        self.small_key = 999
        for v in self.que.keys():
            if self.que[v] < self.small_key:
                self.small_key = self.que[v]
                self.small_v = v
        del self.que[v]
        return self.small_v

    def append(self,u, w):
        self.que[u] = w #adds a vertex to the que with its weight

    def not_empty(self):
        return bool(self.que) #if dict is empty, the value will be false

    def delete(self,u):
        del self.que[u]
```

Comment: Why you are assigning `v` to `self.small_v`? Isn't `v` the key and `self.que[v]` is the value?

Comment: v is just the key. I will later use the v returned by the queue to access the dict in a graph class that will have the vertex object.

Comment: This priority queue is super slow.  You should probably use heapq: https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html

Comment: @MattTimmermans (sigh) I thought so too. I was trying to understand it by creating one myself first and then optimizing it later.